# How to generate files from Liquid blocks in Jekyll?

Tags: plugins, jekyll, liquid

I am writing a [plugin](https://gist.github.com/3469301) that defines a new Jekyll block `ditaa`. Any content in the block should be converted from [Ditaa markup](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) to an image file and that image inserted into the post instead of the block. Generating the file works but when copying into or generating in the `_site` directory, the file is apparently deleted.

Is there a proper/better way to implement a block plugin that generates custom assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the *proper* solution: **use the `Jekyll::StaticFile` class**.

When you add one object of this class to the `site.static_files` array, you are marking this file as pending for copy **after** the render process is completed. In fact, the copy of such files is done in the `site.write` process. Take a look at the `site_process.rb` file in your Jekyll installation.

The usage of this class is easy. When you need to mark a file for future copy, you simply execute a code like this:

```
site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.source, path, filename)
```

Where `path` and `filename` depends on the location of your file in the `src` folder.

I had a similar issue developing a LaTeX -> PNG liquid tag. You can take a look at my code at GitHub: https://github.com/fgalindo/jekyll-liquid-latex-plugin

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did you manage to generate the files outside the source tree (e.g. `/tmp`) and use `StaticFile` to fetch the files from there?

Comment: No, I kept the generated files inside `src`. I duplicate the structure: `src/res/latex` <-> `site/res/latex`. This helps keeping the cache of generated files. If the file is already there, no need to recompile. The plugin removes all temporary and obsolete files (orphaned). Take a look at my code and grab the cleanup procedure if you like or let me cooperate in yours to improve it with a pull request. In fact I discovered `ditaa` thanks to your question, and loved it at first sight.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I actually don't want to keep the generated data in the source tree as it is version controlled in my case. However, checking if it is already copied to `_site` should be possible, right? You are free to issue a pull request ;-) P.S.: I'll update the accepted answer to yours, as it indeed _is_ the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found *the* proper way to do it, but one that works. The solution can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/matze/jekyll-ditaa) and uses Jekylls ability to copy anything that is not prefixed with an underscore to the `_site` directory. However, this approach has also two drawbacks:

1. The "source" directory gets polluted with auto-generated files
2. Deploying without auto-regeneration is a bit awkward because the images are generated *after* Jekyll already copied all files. So a second Jekyll run is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

Replace this

```
site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.source, path, filename)
```

with

```
gnufile = GNUplotFile.new(site, site.source, "_site/media/", "#{@file}")
gnufile.givemethecommands commands
site.static_files << gnufile
```

and create a `GNUplotFile` class that inherits Jekyll::StaticFile

```
class GNUplotFile < Jekyll::StaticFile
  def write(dest)
    puts "WRITE---->>>>>>>>>>>"
    #File.write('_site/media/BTTTTT.svg', DateTime.now)
    gnuplot(@commands)
    # do nothing
  end
  def gnuplot(commands)
    IO.popen("gnuplot", "w") { |io| io.puts commands }
  end
  def givemethecommands(commands)
    @commands = commands
  end
end
```

The write command runs after the cleanup process. I just have a Liquid block and the above code.