# Copying generated files from a Jekyll plugin to a site resource folder

Tags: ruby, plugins, tags, jekyll, liquid

I'm developing a plugin in [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) that inserts a new Liquid Tag (a block tag) named `latex`. It's purpose is to insert a block of LaTeX source code inside a post source file this way:

```
... post file contents ...
{% latex density=300 usepackages=pstricks-all, %}
\pspicture(5,5)
\psframe(0,0)(5,5) \psline(0,0)(5,5) \psline(0,5)(5,0)
\endpspicture
{% endlatex %}
... post file contents ...
```

The output post will contain a `<img>` tag instead of the Liquid Tag block once compiled and the LaTeX source will be compiled by a chained execution of `latex`, `dvips`, `convert`. So it will depend on external programs (TexLive and ImageMagick).

I've not found any issue with the explained so far. I can take the block of LaTeX, put it in a temporary file, and finally compile it to PNG. The rendered files **must** be put in the same folder of the post.

**But just there I'm stuck**: I want to put the generated PNG image to this folder inside the `destination` output folder. No problem defining a site-config variable to define the folder (in fact, I do that), nor put a file there. The problem is simple: **I can write to the `source` folder, but the generated files will not be copied to the `destination` folder**.

I know the reason: Jekyll generates first and renders afterwards. The copy process happens *before* the render part, so the generated files will not be copied.

I've found this SO entry: "[How to generate files from Liquid blocks in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124821/how-to-generate-files-from-liquid-blocks-in-jekyll)", but the answer doesn't feel right: You must make a two-pass build for the files to be copied.

Also found "[Generate file inside _site with Jekyll plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594990/generate-file-inside-site-with-jekyll-plugin)", but this is not applicable because I don't want to render documents by templates.

The solution I've been planning is this:

- Keep a folder with all the generated files and some index strategy for their final placement.
- Implement a `Site`wide method for the final placement procedure, something like:

  ```
  class Site
      def generate_latex_adds
          // Code that copies the generated files to destination folders
      end
  end
  ```
- Add `self.generate_latex_adds` calling that method inside the `site_process.rb` script just before the `self.cleanup` and `self.write` calls.

This will probably solve the problem, **but I feel wrong to modify the `site_process.rb`**. I'm considering pull this Liquid Tag to the community as a GitHub project, and as such, I must document this manual edit of `site_process.rb` to the users of this plugin. I know it's probably a common situation and a common solution, but I wonder if there is a better way to pospone the copy of the generated files without modifying core files. I'd like to keep the plugin simple: just copy the plugin file to the `_plugins` directory.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I'm more interested in the reasoning that on the actual code. I want to learn, not asking for a code solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As anyone has answered my question up to now, and I had kept investigating the issue. Finally I've got an elegant solution: **use the `Jekyll::StaticFile` class**. I have missed that class (sidenote: Read more carefully the docs).

When you add one object of this class to the `site.static_files` array, you are marking this file as pending for copy **after** the render process is completed. In fact, the copy of such files is done in the `site.write` process. Take a look at the `site_process.rb` file in your Jekyll installation.

The usage of this class is easy. When you need to mark a file for future copy, you simply execute a code like this:

```
site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.source, path, filename)
```

Where `path` and `filename` depends on the location of your file in the `src` folder.

And that's all: You generate the files in the `src` folder, mark them as pending for copy and let Jekyll do the rest. **No modification of `site_process.rb` at all!**

You can take a look at the resulting LaTeX -> PNG liquid tag code at GitHub: https://github.com/fgalindo/jekyll-liquid-latex-plugin

I've also implemented a cleanup method there to eliminate orphaned generated files from posts that have been modified and rebuilt.