# Jekyll's is removing static file during cleanup

Tags: plugins, jekyll

I want to include a gnuplot code inside a markdown page and have Jekyll compile the graph when I save it. The graph image is being saved. But it is removed during jekyll's cleanup. The closest that I have found toward a solution is at [Copying generated files from a Jekyll plugin to a site resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835729/copying-generated-files-from-a-jekyll-plugin-to-a-site-resource-folder). However, I don't undersand the overall flow of Jekyll and how I keep static files from being removed. I have added `site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.source, path, filename)` with no results.

If I create a dummy file outside of the _site folder, Jekyll will keep my file safe inside the _site file. I would rather not have to create that dummy file.

Here is code for my plugin.  Any help will be awesome.

```
class RenderGNUplot < Liquid::Block
 def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
  super
  @markup =  markup
  @attributes = {}
  markup.scan(Liquid::TagAttributes) do |key, value|  @attributes[key.to_sym] = value end
 end
 def gnuplot(commands)
  IO.popen("gnuplot", "w") { |io| io.puts commands }
 end
 def render(context)
  site = context.registers[:site]
  @file = ""
  commands =   super 
  if ( commands =~ /set output "(.*)"/ )
   setfile_regex = Regexp.new(/set output "((.*))"/)
   filepath = commands[setfile_regex, 1]
   @file = File.basename filepath
   commands = commands.sub!(commands[setfile_regex], 'set output "_site/media/' + @file +'"' )
   p commands 
  end
  gnuplot(commands)
  site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.source, "_site/media/", "#{@file}")
  # site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticSitemapFile.new(site, site.dest, '/', 'sitemap.xml')
 "<object id='' type='image/svg+xml' data='#{site.baseurl}/media/{@file}'>Your browser does not support SVG</object>"
 end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('test', RenderGNUplot)
```

And Markdown page

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Thin Server"
date:   2015-04-28 10:42:56
categories: thin 
---

{% test location: Test%}
set terminal svg size 600,400 dynamic enhanced fname 'arial'  fsize 10 #mousing jsdir 'http://localhost:4000/media/' name "histograms_1" butt dashlength 1.0
set output "media/curves.svg"
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitle box lt black linewidth 1.000 dashtype solid
set samples 50, 50
set title "Simple Plots" 
set title  font ",20" norotate
plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
{% endtest%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact code that I am using. It only has the Liquid block and jekyll StaticFile

```
class GNUplotFile < Jekyll::StaticFile
    def write(dest)
      puts "WRITE---->>>>>>>>>>>"
      #File.write('_site/media/BTTTTT.svg', DateTime.now)
      gnuplot(@commands)
      # do nothing
    end
    def gnuplot(commands)
      IO.popen("gnuplot", "w") { |io| io.puts commands }
    end
    def givemethecommands(commands)
      @commands = commands
    end
end

class RenderGNUplot < Liquid::Block
  def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
     super
     @markup =  markup
     @attributes = {}
     markup.scan(Liquid::TagAttributes) do |key, value|  @attributes[key.to_sym] = value end
  end

  def render(context)
    site = context.registers[:site]
    @file = ""
    commands =   super 
    if ( commands =~ /set output "(.*)"/ )
      setfile_regex = Regexp.new(/set output "((.*))"/)
      filepath = commands[setfile_regex, 1]
       @file = File.basename filepath
      commands = commands.sub!(commands[setfile_regex], 'set output "_site/media/' + @file +'"' )
      #p commands 
    end
    gnuplot = GNUplotFile.new(site, site.source, "_site/media/", "#{@file}")
    gnuplot.givemethecommands commands
    site.static_files << gnuplot 
    # site.static_files << Jekyll::StaticFile.new(site, site.dest, '/', 'sitemap.xml')
    "<object id='' type='image/svg+xml' data='#{site.baseurl}/media/#{@file}'>Your browser does not support SVG</object>"
  end
end
Liquid::Template.register_tag('test', RenderGNUplot)
```